# NSNotificationCenter - Observer Pattern: Ok, but in mobile apps?

Tags: ios

Why using NSNotificationCenter(ios) in a mobile apps. I mean I dont have many UI controls to update on a View. Also if I need to pass down to the caller of a View I would just use a delegate.

It might be justifiable in a logical sense if I have many Views in a Navigation control, and I would like to have each view down the navigation to update something - it is in situations like this NSNotificationCenter gets into play?

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 1):

In the situations you mention, you probably shouldn't use notifications -- it really doesn't have anything to do with mobile apps, the same criteria would apply to desktop apps as well. Notifications are best used if you need multiple objects to listen for an event, or in some cases, where two view controllers are far apart in the overall scheme of controllers, it's difficult to have one view controller set itself as the delegate of the other.